# Trying to write a wrapper class around Paho MQTT Javascript client

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to write a simple wrapper class around the Paho MQTT JavaScript client.  (The idea is to put some extra validation around MQTT messaging, to ensure messages are processed in the correct order.)

I'm not very comfortable with JavaScript classes, and I'm getting in a mess trying to work out what's wrong with this...

```js
class Hermes {
  constructor(uri, topic, callback) {
    var clientId = "clientID_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000);
    this.client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(uri, clientId);
    this.topic = topic;
    this.callback = callback;
    this.client.onMessageArrived = this._onMessageArrived;
    this.client.onConnectionLost = this._onConnectionLost;
    this.client.connect({
      onSuccess: this._onConnect,
      onFailure: this._onFailure
    });
  }
  _onConnect() {
    // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
    console.log("_onConnect: " + this.client.clientId)
    this.client.subscribe(this.topic);
  }
  // called when connection fails
  _onFailure(responseObject) {
    console.log("_onFailure: "+responseObject.errorMessage);
  }
  // called when a message arrives
  _onMessageArrived(message) {
    console.log("_onMessageArrived: "+message.payloadString)
    // TODO: validate message and pass to callback
  }
  // called when client loses connection
  _onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
      console.log("onConnectionLost: "+responseObject.errorMessage);
    }
  }
}


function handleMessage(message) {
// TODO: handle message
}
var hermes = new Hermes("ws://mqtt.example.com:9001/mqtt", "test", handleMessage);
```

**Expected result:**
`_onConnect: clientID_xxx` should be logged in the console when the client successfully connects.

**Actual result:**

```
onConnectionLost: AMQJS0005E Internal error. Error Message: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.client.clientId'), Stack trace: _onConnect@file:///Users/richardguy/Desktop/hermes.js:16:45
```

The MQTT broker is running on a VPS and I can publish/subscribe messages successfully using the Paho Javascript library outside of a class, like so...

```js
uri = "ws://mqtt.example.com:9001/mqtt"
var clientId = "clientID_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000);
client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(uri, clientId);
client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
client.connect({
  onSuccess: onConnect,
  onFailure: onFailure
});
function onConnect() {
  // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
  console.log("_onConnect: " + client.clientId)
  client.subscribe("test");
}
// called when connection fails
function onFailure(responseObject) {
  console.log("_onFailure: "+responseObject.errorMessage);
}
// called when a message arrives
function onMessageArrived(message) {
  console.log("_onMessageArrived: "+message.payloadString)
  // TODO: validate message and pass to callback
}
// called when client loses connection
function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
  if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
    console.log("onConnectionLost: "+responseObject.errorMessage);
  }
}
```

Is this just a mistake in the class definition, or something to do with the Paho MQTT library??

**Solution:**

I needed to pass an object (in this case the instance of the `Hermes` class) to use as the context for the `onSuccess` callback rather than using `this` (which isn't what I thought it was, as usual...), using `invocationContext` in the connection options.

```js
class Hermes {
  constructor(uri, topic, callback) {
    var clientId = "clientID_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000);
    this.client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(uri, clientId);
    this.topic = topic;
    this.callback = callback;
    this.client.onMessageArrived = this._onMessageArrived;
    this.client.onConnectionLost = this._onConnectionLost;
    this.client.connect({
      onSuccess: this._onConnect,
      onFailure: this._onFailure,
      invocationContext: this
    });
  }
  _onConnect(responseObject) {
    // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
    let self = responseObject.invocationContext;
    self.client.subscribe(self.topic);
  }
  // called when connection fails
  _onFailure(responseObject) {
    console.log("_onFailure: "+responseObject.errorMessage);
  }
  // called when a message arrives
  _onMessageArrived(message) {
    console.log("_onMessageArrived: "+message.payloadString)
    // TODO: validate message and pass to callback
  }
  // called when client loses connection
  _onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
      console.log("onConnectionLost: "+responseObject.errorMessage);
    }
  }
}


function handleMessage(message) {
}
var hermes = new Hermes("ws://mqtt.example.com:8080/mqtt", "test", handleMessage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `this` is not what you think it is.

The callbacks are all made from the clients network handler, so `this` is actually a reference to the handler.

You can pass an object to use as the context for the `onSuccess` and `onFailure` callbacks in the connection options using `invocationContext`, but not for the other callbacks.